# If $\{x_n\}\rightarrow \infty$ and $\{y_n\}$ is bounded then $\{x_n+y_n\}\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm working on proving the above statement, here's what I have so far.

Proof. Suppose $|x_n+y_n|$ is bounded. Then $\exists \ \varepsilon>0$,  such that $|x_n+y_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n$. But $x_n$ is unbounded, so $\forall \ M>0$, $\exists \ N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ implies $x_n>M$. Pick $M>K$, so that if $n\geq N$
$$|y_n|=|(y_n+x_n)-x_n|=|x_n-(x_n+y_n)|\geq |x_n|-|x_n+y_n|>M-K$$

I'm looking for a contradiction, and I don't know where to go from here. I have spent too long on this problem as is, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: $(y_n)$ is bounded, i.e., there exists $d$ such that $|y_n|\leq d$. Put $K=max\{\varepsilon,d\}$ and take $M=3K$ for example.

Comment: My advice would be to try proving it directly. For all $M > 0$, find some $N$ such that $n \ge N \implies x_n + y_n > M$. You already know you can make $x_n$ as large as you like, and you know that $y_n \ge K$ for some $K$ independent of $n$.

Comment: Your relation will give you $K\geq |y_n|>M-K=2K$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: If I suppose there exists an $M>0$ such that $-M<y_n<M$, then since $x_n$ diverges to infinity, $x_n>2M$. Am I then able to make the assumption that $x_n+y_n>2M+y_n>2M-M=M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a simple proof using comparison test. Suppose $|y_n| < M$. Then:
$$
x_n + y_n > x_n- M \to \infty
$$